# Alignment not working in ios14, xcode12 swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, alignment, frame, ios14

My alignment is not working in xcode12 ios14, however, I had same code in xcode11.5 everything was fine . whenever I have added .frame viewModifier to the content alignment is not in the center, is it a bug or has API changed? Here is code : Please check it out in xcode12 , ios14 only.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body : some View {
       
        GeometryReader { geo in
            
            Capsule()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(height: 50)
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
   
}
```

This is also not working:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body : some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            
            Capsule()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(height: 50)
            
        }
        
    }
    }
    
   
}
```

This not working :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body : some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            
            Capsule()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(height: 50, alignment: .center)
            
        }
        
    }
    }
    
   
}
```

Whenever I remove GeometryReader everything is working fine but I want GeometryReader

Comment: Yes, behaviour of `GeometryReader` is different, but it is hard to say which one is more correct. I would recommend to not depend on *implicit* layout, but make layout as you wish explicitly. Submit feedback to Apple and they maybe reply if it is expected.

Comment: should I return back to xcode11.5 Im following a tutorial where they are using xcode12 what is optimal solution

Comment: is it problem with xcode12 or swiftui2.0 or ios14?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following gives you centred capsule in both cases

```
ZStack {
    Capsule()
        .fill(Color.red)
        .frame(height: 50)
}.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue as the OP; this solution didn't fix things. Anything else worth trying?